# Why isn't there a "class" prop for React?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, dom

In `React.DOM.Props` from [purescript-react](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-react/2.0.0/docs/React.DOM.Props), DOM node attributes are nearly exhaustively listed there, *except* for a `class` attribute (I'd suspect it to be named `_class`, similar to `_type` for Purescript's syntax issue). I tried to make my own with

```
_class :: String -> Props
_class = unsafeMkProps "class"
```

And attempted to use it, but after inspecting the HTML, React didn't include the attribute! Why is this? Why can't I use a `class` attribute in my DOM nodes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to use `className` here and not `class`. This is done to prevent confusion between a JavaScript *class* and the DOM attribute *class*.

Here's what the [**official documentation**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#classname) says:

> To specify a CSS class, use the className attribute. This applies to all regular DOM and SVG elements like `<div>`, `<a>`, and others.

It is actually even listed in the page you're linking to, [**here**](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-react/2.0.0/docs/React.DOM.Props#v:className)

```
className :: String -> Props
```

Comment: @AthanClark, you may use this and forget about `className` https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsx-html-class